# Getting error while calling WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

*I am trying to create an API and trying to access it via chrome, expecting it to return the list of Items*

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    Product product = new Product();
    List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetTheProduct(int id)
    {
        this.productList.Add(new Product {Id = 111,Name= "sandeep" });
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, this.productList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 111));
    }
}
```

I have not added route so wanna run it using default route but when i am running it, am getting

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request
>   URI 'http://localhost:65098/api/GetTheProduct()'. 
>    No type was found that matches the controller named
>   'GetTheProduct()'.

Suggest me what all things are required to make it work.

Comment: Try using .../api/product/gettheproduct/11 for example?

Comment: yes i tried to use http://localhost:65098/api/product/gettheproduct/111    still getting error

Comment: Posting your WebAPIConfig.cs code might help to find the issue.

Comment: Try: http://localhost:65098/api/product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using default routes then configuration may look like this

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

This would mean that routing is using convention-based routing with the following route template `"api/{controller}/{id}"`

Your controller in its current state is not following the convention. This results in requests not being matched in the route tables which result in the Not Found issues being experienced.

Refactor the controller to follow the convention

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController {
    List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();

    public ProductsController() {
        this.productList.Add(new Product { Id = 111, Name = "sandeep 1" });
        this.productList.Add(new Product { Id = 112, Name = "sandeep 2" });
        this.productList.Add(new Product { Id = 113, Name = "sandeep 3" });
    }

    //Matched GET api/products
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get() {
        return Ok(productList);
    }

    //Matched GET api/products/111
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) {
        var product = productList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id));
        if(product == null)
            return NotFound();
        return Ok(product); 
    }
}
```

Finally based on the route template configured then the controller expects a request that looks like

```
http://localhost:65098/api/products/111.
```

To get a single product that matches the provided `id` if it exists.

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Thanks dear i was looking for the same explaination